# How to create a modified line plot?

Tags: plotting, visualization

I am looking for help to create a Line Plot that looks something like the image below.
[image: Line Plot Image]

The NumberLinePlot function works well if you have a sets of distinct values,  but this plot would create stacks of common values as shown.   I tried all the "data visualization" help files, but unless I missed an option,  didn't find anything that would help to make this happen.

Sample data is below, hoping to stack on "tenths"

```
data = {5.1, 7.3, 6.9, 4.7, 5.0, 6.2, 6.4, 5.5, 5.7, 6.8, 6.0, 4.8, 4.1, \
5.2, 8.1, 6.3, 7.5, 5.0, 5.7, 8.2, 3.3, 3.1, 4.3, 5.9, 6.6, 5.8, 6.4, \
6.1, 4.6, 5.7}
```

Comment: The range of your sample data is limited: `MinMax[data] == {3.1, 8.2}`. What is the full range of the data? Is it `1. <= data < 10.`? The full range changes how the plot is drawn.

Comment: That is the actual data (a question in a math textbook,  life spans of car batteries!   Likely made up data....

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
gathered = Gather @ Sort @ Round @ data;
```

#### NumberLinePlot

```
nlpdata = Join[## & @@ Map[List, gathered, {-1}], 2];

NumberLinePlot[nlpdata, 
 PlotStyle -> Directive[AbsolutePointSize[10], ColorData[97]@1]]
```

[image]

#### Histogram + ChartLayout

```
Histogram[nlpdata, {1},
  ChartStyle -> ColorData[97]@1, Axes -> {True, False}, 
  ChartLayout -> "Stacked", PerformanceGoal -> "Speed"] /. 
 Rectangle[a_, b_, ___] :> Disk[Mean[{a, b}], Offset[7]]
```

[image]

#### Histogram + ChartElements

```
Histogram[Round@data, {1}, 
 ChartElements -> {Graphics[Disk[{0, 0}, Offset[7]]], {All, 1}}, 
 Axes -> {True, False}]
```

[image]

#### ListPlot

```
ListPlot[MapIndexed[Thread[{#, #2[[1]]}] &] /@ gathered, 
 PlotStyle -> Directive[AbsolutePointSize[10], ColorData[97]@1], 
 AspectRatio -> 1/2,
 Axes -> {True, False}, 
 PlotRange -> {{1, 9}, All}, 
 Ticks -> {Range @ 9, None}]
```

[image]

#### BubbleChart

```
BubbleChart[{#, #2, #2} & @@@ Tally[Round@data], 
  BubbleSizes -> {.07, .07}, 
  Frame -> {{False, False}, {True, False}},
  PlotRange -> {Automatic, {1, All}}] /. 
 Disk[{a_, b_}, c_] :> (Disk[{a, #}, c] & /@ Range[b])
```

[image]

#### Graphics

```
Graphics[{AbsolutePointSize[15], ColorData[97]@1, 
  Point[Join @@ (Thread[{#, Range @ #2}] & @@@ Tally[Round @ data])]}, 
 AspectRatio -> 1, Axes -> {True, False}, 
 AxesOrigin -> {Automatic, 0}, 
 PlotRangePadding -> {{1, 1}/2, Automatic}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

One way to do this is the following:

```
data = {5.1, 7.3, 6.9, 4.7, 5.0, 6.2, 6.4, 5.5, 5.7, 6.8, 6.0, 4.8, 
   4.1, 5.2, 8.1, 6.3, 7.5, 5.0, 5.7, 8.2, 3.3, 3.1, 4.3, 5.9, 6.6, 
   5.8, 6.4, 6.1, 4.6, 5.7};
lsPoints =
  GroupBy[Round[data], Identity];
lsPoints = KeyValueMap[Thread[{#1, Range[Length[#2]]}] &, lsPoints];

ListPlot[lsPoints, Axes -> {True, False}, PlotStyle -> Directive[{PointSize[0.02], ColorData["Rainbow", 0.28]}]]
```

(`data` is with the sample data from the question.)

[image]